# std::equal error while compiling with -std=gnu++11 switch

Tags: c++, vector, std

This loop works fine when I compile without the -std=gnu++11 switch. If I compile with the -std=gnu++11 I get the following error:

```
no match for call to '(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const float*, std::vector<float> >) (const float&, const float&)' if (!bool(__binary_pred(*__first1, *__first2)))
```

My code:

```
for (auto it_A = std::begin(vector_A); it_A != std::end(vector_A); it_A += 4)
{
    bool found_in_B = false;
    for (auto it_B = std::begin(vector_B); !found_in_B && it_B != std::end(vector_B); it_B += 4)
    {
        found_in_B = std::equal(it_A, it_A + blockSize, it_B, it_B + blockSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be it_A < std::end (vector_A)? I mean, I don't really know size of element of Vector_A

Comment: Why do you want to use this switch?

Comment: @krubo Is that relavent?

Comment: it is relevent, because I have another library that is compiled in -std=gnu++11

Comment: @AniketChowdhury the code is functionally correct. I do not know why I get this error by this switch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up until C++14, `std::equal` takes three iterators: Two describing the first range, and one describing the beginning of the second range. There'd be no reason for it to take a fourth iterator, because both ranges have to be the same length (again, up until C++14).

The four-iterator version was added in C++14, and is not available with your chosen language variant (that flag affects the standard library, not just the language).

Since the range lengths will always match in your code, you can just drop the fourth parameter.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense :)